# Count occurrences of values from one dataframe in another

Tags: pandas, dataframe, count, cross-reference

I need to create another column in df1 that will tell me a count of occurrences. Note, that another dataframe does not have exact match but does contain the values.

df1:

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5
```

df2:

```
user1,user2
user2, user1
user1, user5
user4,user5
```

I tried:

```
df1['Newcount'] = df1['df1:'].map(df2['df2:'].value_counts())
```

But this counts exact matches.

The desired output should be:

```
user1  3
user2  2
user3  0
user4  1
user5  2
```

Comment: What is `df2` exactly? Are the commas column separators or are they part of the data? Please make a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Why did you change the semicolons to commas? That doesn't change my question, if that's why.

Comment: To make it more clear. Its just data and I need I to extract "user1" and count it either if it appears by itself or within another string.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4', 'user5']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['user1;user2', 'user2;user1', 'user1;user5', 'user4;user5']})

df1.merge(
    df2.assign(
        col=df2['col'].str.split(';')
        ).explode('col').value_counts().reset_index(),
    how='left'
    ).fillna(0)


    col     0
0   user1   3.0
1   user2   2.0
2   user3   0.0
3   user4   1.0
4   user5   2.0
```

Comment: You can skip the `assign` since it just replaces `col`. `df2['col'].str.split(';').explode()`...